# Rails: best way to turn these requests into a counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, counter-cache

I've got several of these requests each page load:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `impressions` WHERE `impressions`.`impressionable_id` IN (229) AND `impressions`.`impressionable_type` = 'Document' AND (YEAR(created_at) = 2013 && MONTH(created_at) = 8 && DAY(created_at) = 12)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `impressions` WHERE `impressions`.`impressionable_id` IN (229) AND `impressions`.`impressionable_type` = 'Document' AND (YEAR(created_at) = 2013 && MONTH(created_at) = 8 && DAY(created_at) = 13)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `impressions` WHERE `impressions`.`impressionable_id` IN (229) AND `impressions`.`impressionable_type` = 'Document' AND (YEAR(created_at) = 2013 && MONTH(created_at) = 8 && DAY(created_at) = 14)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `impressions` WHERE `impressions`.`impressionable_id` IN (229) AND `impressions`.`impressionable_type` = 'Document' AND (YEAR(created_at) = 2013 && MONTH(created_at) = 8 && DAY(created_at) = 15)
```

I'd like to reduce load on the server so I'm trying to turn it into a `counter_cache` solution. I need a bit of help designing it because of the complex relationship I'm trying to count. Here's the query that gets the counts:

```
Impression.where(:impressionable_id => component.publications.where(:document_id => document).first.id).count
```

Where should I put the `counter_cache` column? And how should I write the migration? `Component` and `Document` are in a `has_many` relationship through `Publications`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming impression counts are for `Publication`, and impression count is to be grouped by each day.

You could create `PublicationImpression` model to serve as a counter for the impression of each `Publication` per day.

```
class CreatePublicationImpressions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :publication_impressions, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :impressions, :default => 0
      t.datetime :date
      t.references :publication

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :publication_impressions
  end
end
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I don't know if it was clear in my question, though, but I'm counting `Impressions` based on **both** `Component` and `Document`. I'm trying to figure out how best to implement that.

Comment: add the counter field to publication? I'm assuming `Publication` is unique for each pair of `Component` and `Document`

Comment: Yeah, `Publication` is unique. It's the join table between `Component` and `Document`. I was hoping to use that one instead of creating a similar table.

Comment: You would still need to create a new table for counter as the counts should be grouped by per day basis too. I have updated my answer to reflect that change.